# Branch strategy for parallel working and 'breaking changes'

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

We have an application which has historically suffered a high number of branches.

These have now been ratified, but a situation has now occurred where we have two development streams (which ideally would be one) and one of these streams requires a number of changes where implementing them will have knock on effects which aren't fixable as part of a single story (or possibly a single sprint).

**For example:** a high number of database schema changes which require a large number of query logic changes.

These changes aren't easily feature flagged as they systematically break existing functionality until the work if completed. We could theoretically put the system back in a 'building' state, but it would prevent the customer from using the existing functionality.

To cater for this, we're proposing creating a new branch for the 'breaking changes' so that the other development stream isn't broken and can be released intermittently.

Whilst I'm loathed to create new branches, I can't see a better way of doing this at the moment.

Is there a recommended practice, either branch strategy to manage or architecturally to protect from, breaking changes in parallel development?

**EDIT:** The only other thing which has crossed my mind is to literally 'copy-paste' the existing functionality (including tables/web pages etc) renaming them and working on that in the same branch, behind a feature flag. 
This is obviously pretty messy for a number of reasons!

Does anyone have any suggestions for how they have coped with this in the past?

Answer (score 1):

You should deliver the database schema (and other changes) in an incremental fashion. Don't take on the whole change at once, but instead break it down into things that you can deliver.

If your current application architecture does not support this model then that is the first problem to tackle.

Always meet your DoD for every Sprint. All work integrated with no further work required to ship...

Comment: In an ideal world, certainly. What's causing us problems is that the schema changes are too large for one sprint, and making them requires lots of changes to existing areas. 
The knock on impact of these changes is significant to the DAL, BLL & UI simultaneously.
The main issue is that, the amount of effort required to ensure we can deliver incrementally in this case is massive, compared to allowing the 'trunk' to become unstable for a period of time. Given this, would you suggest that the separate branch may be the lesser of two evils? or would you strive to achieve things on a single branch?

Comment: I cant make that call. Only you business can. Do you still need to deliver value to customers while you are refactoring? If so you have to go with #1. Otherwise you get two divergant codebase

Comment: You can always break it down. Make smaller changes. A single table at a time maybe.

Comment: This would certainly be a possibility, but the knock on impact of changing all impacted areas many times would be a potentially huge cost.

Say we have a complex report, amending this each time we change a table is depends is, is a greater effort than changing it once, after all tables have been changed. I guess we have to make a judgement call on releasibility vs maintenance effort.